# django time checker database

Tags: python, django, postgresql, python-multithreading

I am trying to create a thread function that allow me to check a database field in order to see if the time.now() is bigger than the one recorded in the database(postgresql); the problem is that the view.py where I am calling this, is blocked by this thread, this is my actual code:

PD: expire_pet is a text field, then I cast it to datetime.

```
import socket
import struct
from time import *
from datetime import datetime
from models import Zone
from multiprocessing import pool
import threading

class ControlHora(threading.Thread):

        def __init__(self,zone_id):
                threading.Thread.__init__(self)
                self.zone_id = zone_id

        def run(self):

                while(True):

                        zone_pet = Zone.objects.filter(id = self.zone_id)

                        for i in zone_pet:
                                if i.pet_state == True:
                                        hour = datetime.datetime.strptime(i.expire_pet, '%I:%M')
                                        if hour <= datetime.datetime.now():
                                                Zone.objects.filter(id = self.zone_id).update(vitrasa_pet = False)
                                                Zone.objects.filter(id = self.zone_id).update(esycsa_pet = False)
                                                Zone.objects.filter(id = self.zone_id).update(pet_state = False)
                                                Zone.objects.filter(id = self.zone_id).update(expire_pet='')
                                sleep(5)
```

Comment: Time out is showing in the client side if I call that thread

Answer (score 0):

It works, the problem was that I have been calling the run in the wrong place, thanks